# In Chrome, how can I get the javascript console output to stdout/stderr

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome, and have a page that prints some information to the Javascript console - I want to pipe this to a script.

I've found how to display Chrome's stdout on OS X - by running the command below from a Terminal (a new user profile is needed to make sure the command spawns a new application, otherwise we'll open the existing one and get no output).

However, all I'm getting printed to Terminal is internal Chrome information.

Is there a way to get all JS console output to be printed to stdout/stderr so that I can pipe the output of the below command to my script?

TIA!

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=temp-dir

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Enable [logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) from the command line using the flags:

  `--enable-logging --v=stderr`

This logs everything Chrome does internally, but it also logs all the `console.log()` messages as well.  The log file is called **`chrome_debug.log`** and is located in the [`User Data Directory`](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

Comment: Not quite right, but your tip got me there, so thanks!  

If I enable logging **and** force a temp user directory (which I need to do on OS X, as mentioned before) then I don't see the output in the debug file you mentioned.  On a hunch I went looking, and indeed there is a file `temp-dir/chrome_debug.log` which contains the output I want :)

So the answere is `--enable-logging --v=1 --user-data-dir=temp-dir` to get what I need on OS X.

Comment: `--enable-logging=stderr` is possible also

Comment: Hey, do you know by chance how that would be for Firefox?

Comment: The `chrome_debug.log` in this case will be full of data that do not appear on the console, which makes it impossible to parse.

Comment: This works perfectly on a raspberry pi version 10 buster - this a debian.  to view the log I used: sudo tail -f /rds/home/rds-user/.config/chromium/chrome_debug.log